# How to output an image to pdf in table specific php code?

Tags: php

I am being asked to only add code to the following function. I want to output a logo and additional text if possible. And the content of the export document is $this->ExportDoc->Text. I am using the following but it's not working.

The original example is

```
function Page_Exporting() {
    $this->ExportDoc->Text = "my header";
        return TRUE; 
}
```

I tried the following and they wouldn't work

```
function Page_Exporting() {
    $this->ExportDoc->Text('logo.jpg');
        return TRUE; 
}
```

or
I tried to add additional lines, the second always replace the previous, they refuse to show at the same time....

```
function Page_Exporting() {
    $this->ExportDoc->Text = "my header1";
        $this->ExportDoc->Text = "my header2";
        return TRUE; 
}
```

I just want to add logo.jpg and couple lines to the top of the pdf I want to export from php code.

Answer (score 1):

With this lib it seems easier !

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Example of the official documentation :

https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#images

PHPWord can generate pdf !

In other hand, are you sure about your path ?

```
 $this->ExportDoc->Text('logo.jpg');
```

logo.jpg is on the same path as your php script ?

For example to get the current path of your script use `__DIR__`.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php
And finaly had the absolute path use `realpath`.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Example of code :

```
$path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/Asset/images/logo.png');
```

ExportDoc isn't a php native capability, so what are you using ?

Comment: ExportDoc is by cpdf.  Thank you so much!  It worked!!  =D

Comment: That’s a good news ! Wish you the best for your futur coding ;) please mark my respond as valid response ! Like that the topic is closed  !